# Convert an ndArray of set to a matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I have a dataset loaded from file -

```
np.array([(5.1, 3.5, 1.4, 0.2, 'Iris-setosa'),
          (4.9, 3., 1.4, 0.2, 'Iris-setosa'),
          (4.7, 3.2, 1.3, 0.2, 'Iris-setosa'),
          (4.6, 3.1, 1.5, 0.2, 'Iris-setosa'),
          (5., 3.6, 1.4, 0.2, 'Iris-setosa')])
```

How do I get a matrix of the first 4 columns -

```
np.array([[5.1, 3.5, 1.4, 0.2],
          [4.9, 3., 1.4, 0.2],
          [4.7, 3.2, 1.3, 0.2],
          [4.6, 3.1, 1.5, 0.2],
          [5., 3.6, 1.4, 0.2]])
```

and the labels into another array-

```
np.array(['Iris-setosa', 'Iris-setosa', 'Iris-setosa', 'Iris-setosa',
          'Iris-setosa'])
```

Comment: Your input is not valid Python. Please supply a correct definition of your input.

Comment: What is the `dtype` of this array?  With the `()` I'm guessing it's a structured array, possibly produced by `genfromtxt`.  If so the string 'column' is easily accessed by name, `arr['f4']`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

data=np.array([(5.1, 3.5, 1.4, 0.2, 'Iris-setosa') ,
 (4.9, 3. , 1.4, 0.2, 'Iris-setosa'),
 (4.7, 3.2, 1.3, 0.2, 'Iris-setosa'),
 (4.6, 3.1, 1.5, 0.2, 'Iris-setosa'),
 (5. , 3.6, 1.4, 0.2, 'Iris-setosa')])

df= pd.DataFrame(data)
first4col = df.iloc[:,0:3]
tags=df.iloc[:,4]
```